# App keeping own contacts - no syncing with Contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I'm looking for some app that will be a separated app, where I can keep my contacts, which are not needed in my typical Contacts list. I believe you know, what I mean... if I have some phone number and would like to write it down, I don't want to place it in my Contacts list and makes there a mess.
Noting in Notes is a bit silly and not native. I want something like "Contacts" as a separate app, which doesn't connect with my typical contacts list.

Do you know anything like that? I couldn't find or cannot search :P

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate address books and groups to organize your contacts. But, everything will be exposed through Contacts app.

Comment: It still makes a mess for me.